# SQL Error 4104 : The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a project in which I have to use a database to store data from a cinema. One of the tables stores some movies data(movie name, duration actors, etc) and it has a image column; I left it null so that I could take care of the login first and then inserted the ovies but didn't insert the image, and now when I try to insert the image it gives this error.

> The multi-part identifier "Filmes.Titulo_Filme" could not be bound.

The code I'm using to insert the image is this:

```
insert into Filmes (Imagem) select * from OPENROWSET(BULK N'F:\RC\RC8\Projecto\ShikiHD_ASP\ShikiHD_ASP\Images\bohemianrhapsody.jpeg', SINGLE_BLOB) as image where Filmes.Titulo_Filme = 'Bohemian Rhapsody'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I tried to update the column since I already had all the other columns filled and it still didn't work, but now it gives another error.

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

The code for the update:

```
update Filmes set Imagem = (select * from OPENROWSET(BULK N'F:\RC\RC8\Projecto\ShikiHD_ASP\ShikiHD_ASP\Images\bohemianrhapsody.jpeg', SINGLE_BLOB) as image) where Filmes.Titulo_Filme = 'Bohemian Rhapsody'
```

Comment: Please specify the database language you are using (looks like SQL Server from `OPENROWSET`), as "SQL" is a family of languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
insert into Filmes (Imagem)
    select *
    from OPENROWSET(BULK N'F:\RC\RC8\Projecto\ShikiHD_ASP\ShikiHD_ASP\Images\bohemianrhapsody.jpeg', SINGLE_BLOB) as image
    where Filmes.Titulo_Filme = 'Bohemian Rhapsody'
```

`Filmes` is not defined.  `image` is.  So perhaps you mean:

```
insert into Filmes (Imagem)
    select imagen
    from OPENROWSET(BULK N'F:\RC\RC8\Projecto\ShikiHD_ASP\ShikiHD_ASP\Images\bohemianrhapsody.jpeg', SINGLE_BLOB) as image
    where image.Titulo_Filme = 'Bohemian Rhapsody';
```

Or perhaps you really want an `update`:

```
update filmes
    set imagem = i.image
    from OPENROWSET(BULK N'F:\RC\RC8\Projecto\ShikiHD_ASP\ShikiHD_ASP\Images\bohemianrhapsody.jpeg', SINGLE_BLOB) as i(image)
    where filmes.Titulo_Filme = 'Bohemian Rhapsody';
```

Comment: I tried both ways and both didnt work. It gave an Invalid column name error in both Titulo_Filme and Image(in your answer you have "imagen", I tried it and it didnt work either and switched it to image, Imagem and still didnt work). The update said "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated".

Answer (score 1):

As per your statement you have already inserted data in all the fields other than `image` field of `Filmes` table.

So instead of inserting you need to update the column as follows. Also you need to ensure brackets are added at proper places.

```
UPDATE Filmes
SET Imagem = 
    (SELECT  BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK   N'F:\RC\RC8\Projecto\ShikiHD_ASP\ShikiHD_ASP\Images\bohemianrhapsody.jpeg' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)
WHERE Filmes.Titulo_Filme = 'Bohemian Rhapsody'
```

Comment: I tried that and it still gives the same error: "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run following queries separately. So you will come to know which query throws error.
FIRST QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM Filmes  WHERE Filmes.Titulo_Filme = 'Bohemian Rhapsody'
```

SECOND QUERY

```
SELECT  BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK   N'F:\RC\RC8\Projecto\ShikiHD_ASP\ShikiHD_ASP\Images\bohemianrhapsody.jpeg' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
```

Comment: The first query returned all columns of that movie. The second one returned the byte array of the image in question. Non of them give any sort of error when separated just when they are together.

Comment: Please verify datatype of "Imagem" column. It should be "image"

Comment: I feel really dumb now, I should have checked that first. But that was it, Thanks.

Comment: No - don't use image. That was deprecated in 2005. Use varbinary(max).

Comment: Thanks for the advice @SMor